# SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl

I am getting this error while sending email. I am using `codeigniter` framework.
Below file is `codeigniter` default file.

> Severity: Warning
>
> fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1846

It wasn't like this before. This is my sending email function.

```
    $ci = get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('email');
    $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = SMTP_HOST;
    $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
    $config['smtp_user'] = SMTP_USER;
    $config['smtp_pass'] = SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
    $config['mailtype'] = "html";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    
    $ci->email->clear(TRUE);
    $ci->email->initialize($config);
    
    $ci->email->from(SMTP_USER, 'something');
    $ci->email->to(array($email));
    $this->email->reply_to(SMTP_USER, 'Customer Reply');
    $ci->email->subject($subject);
    $ci->email->message($message);
    if($attachment!=''){
        $ci->email->attach($attachment);
    }
    $ci->email->send();
```

Comment: what's in the SMTP_HOST? Is it behind a firewall? Can you give the hostname, so that we can test with openssl?

Comment: Yes sure. It's `ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net`

Comment: if you try `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtpout.secureserver.net:465` , you'll see there is nothing in response from the server. "SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 340 bytes" So perhaps can you try talking to godaddy support about this

Comment: ok.. so, it's go daddy issue. thanks.

Comment: @Alexey: They are saying that everything is running fine from their end. May be it's server related issue. My website is running on windows azure server.

Comment: the thing is that I tried from a vagrant ubuntu box and could not connect to 465 port of smtpout.secureserver.net , nor smtpout.europe.secureserver.net , nor relay-hosting.secureserver.net. Weird

Comment: @Alexey: What should I do in order to send email and overcome above error? Is there any way to not use SSL?

Comment: BTW, did you get this error on your local machine or directly on the godaddy server?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: I am getting same errors for CI Email library. I did not changed code. It was working fine for last few month and it started showing these error for last 2 days. We did not made any changes to server as well. 
We are at AWS.

Comment: did either of you ever discover the source of this problem?